# Access to React state with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, puppeteer

I have a React application running. I'd like to know if it's possible to access state values using Puppeteer.

For example, in React I have:

`const [gridBlocks, setGridBlocks] = useState([])`

This value is later updated to set `gridBlocks` to an array of values.

Then, using Puppeteer I have:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
  });

  // Can I get access to React and other javascript values now?
  // Something like console.log(await page.evaluate(() => <are React variables available here>));
  // Another way?

await browser.close();
})();
```

The `gridBlocks` state has values that I'd like to loop through to update the UI and grab screenshot of each. I won't know what the `gridBlocks` values are ahead of time so I can't just "hard code" them in my Puppeteer script. I really like to be able to read it from the loaded page, from `page.goto`.

*Most articles I've seen deal with testing and they pass `props` to components. I'd like to read directly from the loaded page ... if possible.*

Thanks!

Comment: If you are testing a component that uses the `useState` hook, the most probable scenario is that the `gridBlocks` variable in your code is not accessible.

What you should be testing with puppeteer is that when `gridBlocks` is updated, the generated HTML corresponds to what you would expect. You can do so with the methods provided by `page` (for example [page.$(selector)](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-pageselector).

Comment: You might be able to [inject proxy functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55576899/5627599) to access the desired values. For example: Is the `gridBlocks` variable passed to any native JavaScript function?

Answer (score 6):

I found a quick and dirty way to do this on puppeteer. First you need to grab the extension file from chrome. This method is faster than cloning the react repository from github and whatnot.

There are two major steps,

1. Load the extension and devtools.
2. Trick the devtools into selecting the component.

---

First steps:

1. First install [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin)
2. Now download the zip file for [React Developers Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en).
3. Now unzip it into your project as a folder, I chose `extension` for name.

Load the extension, make sure to **keep the devtools open**.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    devtools: true,
    args: [
      '--disable-extensions-except=./extension/',
      '--load-extension=./extension/',
    ]
});
```

Open the react page, and make sure **it is fully loaded**.

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://localhost:3000', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
```

Now, we will find the child element from the root element and use the internal commands used in the devtools.

The waitFor is important as well. We should give it some time to initializing the selection.

```
await page.evaluate(()=>{
    const rootElement = document.querySelector('#root').childNodes[0];
    __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.reactDevtoolsAgent.selectNode(rootElement);
})

await page.waitFor(1000);
```

Finally we have the state for this particular element inside **$r**,

```
const data = await page.evaluate(()=>{
    return $r;
})
```

I couldn't do much with it on the node context, but I'm sure you can modify and execute different stuff using this.

Full code,

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    devtools: true,
    args: [
      '--disable-extensions-except=./extension/',
      '--load-extension=./extension/',
    ]
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

  await page.evaluate(()=>{
    const rootElement = document.querySelector('#root').childNodes[0];
    __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.reactDevtoolsAgent.selectNode(rootElement);
  })

  await page.waitFor(1000);

  const data = await page.evaluate(()=>{
    return $r;
  })

  console.log(data)
})();
```

Here is the example react app,

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

[image]

Note:

- If you don't open the devtools or select the node, it won't work.
- It probably won't work on headless mode on current 1.19 version.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in headless mode? Puppeteer doesn't allow extensions to load on headless, but maybe there's a way to use page.evaluate to load the relelvant React DevTools code.

Answer (score 1):

You are best off leaving puppeteer for Cypress with cypress-react-selector or Webdriver.io for accessing reacts components, props and state.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into HTMLElement's "__reactInternalInstance$randomName" property to find the props values. You may need a help of devtools or loop through all keys in the element to get the actual key name of "__reactInternalInstance$randomName"

```
document.querySelector(".target-element").__reactInternalInstance$randomName.memoizedProps
```

In memoizedProps, keep looking and expanding "children" and "props" properties, the props are hidden somewhere in these two properties.